# Google + Integration fails on Android M device

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin

Using following link : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating I have integrated google sign in to my project.  the code is same as in link like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Button btn;
    int RC_SIGN_IN =100;
    String TAG ="Google";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                    }
                } /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();


        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());


        btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignout);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signOut();
            }
        });
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Signout",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);

           // GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
          /*  GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
            String personId = acct.getId();
            Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();*/
        }
    }
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
           /* mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
            updateUI(true);*/
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success "+ personName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
          //  updateUI(false);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failure "+ result.getStatus(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

This works find on Kitkat device but on android M device it shows

> Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}

Firstly, I thought that maybe Json file issue but if it is, it should not work on any device. It is running successful on kitkat 4.2.2 device but getting failure on android M device. so whats wrong with this?

After all answers I did following simple code :

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

It worked on my E mail Id, but when i use the same code on other device and different email, it is showing me same error. and when i tried to add server_client id it is showing status =12501 error. i dont know what is wrong with code still.

Answer (score 0):

With Android Marshmallow were introduced Android runtime permissions, so if your device's system version is at least 6.0  you should provide user this feature

Read here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

To avoid implementing this feature, go to your `app/build.gradle` and downgrade
`targetSdkVersion` to 22. So your `build.gradle` should look like:

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.piotr.netgururecruit"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 22 //downgrade this value to 22 or 21 to avoid runtime permissions 
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Since 6.0 some permissions are considered as "dangerous".
```

To protect the user, they have to be authorized at runtime, so the user know if it's related to his action. You can check complete example on below link:
 https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-marshmallow-permissions.html

add this 2 permission in menifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Yes but which permissions do i need to give for sign in?

Comment: Google + sign requires GET_ACCOUNTS permission.please check my updated answer.

Comment: If you follow the [latest version of the Sign In docs](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/improving-security-and-user-experience.html) you don't need the GET_ACCOUNTS permission anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to pass your google_server_client_id 


GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_server_client_id))
            .requestServerAuthCodegetString(R.string.google_server_client_id)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Comment: I did the above code and now getting following error.

Comment: Bundle[{googleSignInStatus=Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}}]